# Calling methods from one class to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two classes. One contains data and behavior. Another is just for input and display of data. When I call the methods of one class from another for displaying the result it returns zero.

Any help...thanks

Data and behavior:

```
class CalculateArea
{
    private const double PI = 3.14;
    private double cirArea;
    private double recArea;
    private double cilArea;
    private double radius;
    private double length, width;
    private int height;

    // Constructors
    public CalculateArea(double radius1) 
    {
        radius = radius1;
    }
    public double CalculateCircleArea()
    {
        cirArea = (PI * (radius * radius));
        return cirArea;
    }

    public CalculateArea(int height1) 
    {
        height = height1;
    }

    public CalculateArea(double lenght1 , double width1) 
    {
        length = lenght1;
        width = width1;

    }

    //public CalculateArea()
    //{
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    //}

    // methods


    //
    public double CalculateRectangleArea() 
    {
        recArea = (length * width);
        return recArea;
    }
    //
    public double CalculateCylinderArea() 
    {
        cilArea = (PI * (radius * radius) * height);
        return cilArea;
    }
}
```

Input and display:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string number;
        Console.WriteLine("Which figure do you want to see calculated select a number");
        Console.WriteLine("Circle : 1");
        Console.WriteLine("Rectangle : 2");
        Console.WriteLine("Cylinder : 3");

        number= Console.ReadLine();
        int numb=Convert.ToInt32(number);

        if (numb == 1) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the radius for circle");
            string rad;
            rad = Console.ReadLine();
            int radiusX = Convert.ToInt32(rad);
            CalculateArea newCal1 = new CalculateArea(radiusX);
            Console.WriteLine("The result of calculation is {0}", newCal1.CalculateCircleArea());
        }

        else if(numb == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the length ");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            double lenght;
            lenght = Convert.ToDouble(number);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the width ");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            double width;
            width = Convert.ToDouble(number);
            CalculateArea newCal2=new CalculateArea(lenght , width);
            Console.WriteLine("The result of calculation is {0}" , newCal2.CalculateRectangleArea());
        }

        else if (numb == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the height ");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            int height;
            height = Convert.ToInt32(number);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the radius");
            number = Console.ReadLine();
            int radius;
            radius = Convert.ToInt32(number);
            CalculateArea newCal3 = new CalculateArea(height, radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The reslut of calculation is {0}", newCal3.CalculateCylinderArea());
        }

        else 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no any calculation number check the information and try again");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: What are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I want to return the calculated but every time it returns 0

Comment: the calculated result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code:

```
CalculateArea newCal1 = new CalculateArea(radiusX);
```

Is calling the following constructor:

```
public CalculateArea(int height1) 
{
    height = height1;
}
```

Because radiusX is an INTEGER...

So, the value is stored in height, not in radius.
Thus, when you call the method to calculate the area of the circle, it computes using radius, that is still 0.0.

The CalculateCylinderArea is using also radius and height, but your constructor is taking only two parameters, height and width.
So, in method 3, it also "fails", as radius and width is 0.0

The computing of the rectangle works.

To solve the problem with the circle, you need to change the raiusX variable to double.

To solve the problem with the cylinder, for example, you could change the routine to use length and width instead of radius and height.

But as a side note, there are still better ways to do what you are trying to do :)

Comment: See my update answer. Only method 1 and 3 fails. Method 2 is working as it should.

Comment: Thank you got it .

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Jauch's answer I would like to give some additional information.

If several methods in a type (class or struct) have the same name, they are said to be overloaded. This is only allowed if they have different formal parameter lists. The names of the parameters don't matter; only their number and their types. Also the return type does not matter.

Your problem has to do with [Overload resolution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx). This is what C# does in order to figure out which overloaded version has to be called. It is important to understand that this happens at compile time, and not at run time. The implication is that the concrete values passed don't matter, since they are not known at compile time. Only the types of the actual arguments matter.

Please follow the link above for the specification, but Jon Skeet's article is probably more digestible: [C# in Depth: Overloading](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx).